# _data.json variables not being loaded

Tags: json, harp

I've set up Harp, and it is running and serving content, but any values stored in `_data.json` seem to have no effect.

Directory structure:

```
/
|-- _harp.json
|-- _data.json
|-- _layout.ejs
|-- index.md
|-- getting-started.md
```

The file `_harp.json` contains:

```
{
        "globals": {
                "title": "Home"
        }
}
```

`_data.json` contains:

```
{
        "getting-started": {
                "title": "Getting Started"
        }
}
```

And `_layout.ejs` contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <title><%= title %> &mdash; My Website</title>
        </head>
        <body>
               <%- yield %>
        </body>
</html>
```

The layout, and page contents, load correctly, and `<%= title %>` is replaced with the value given in `_harp.json`. However, when an entry exists within `_data.json`, no replacement is made and it continues to be replaced with the value in `_harp.json`.

Have I missed the obvious with this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Harp required a restart, although this wasn't mentioned in Harp's documentation. It also appears to require a restart each time `_data.json` is modified.

Comment: You shouldn't need a re-start it. Were you running it as single server, multihost, or simply using compile?

Comment: Harp was just running as a single server.

Answer (score 0):

### The solution

I've run into the same problem, and just found the solution.

It appears in my case, the harp server was launched with `NODE_ENV=production` which has exactly this side effect (see https://harpjs.com/docs/environment/server in the end of the page).
Explicitly set `NODE_ENV=development` solved the problem.

### More informations on environment

https://harpjs.com/docs/development/environment

### Note

`NODE_ENV=development` is the default, you need to explicitly set `NODE_ENV=production` for production purpose.

In my case, I use an already built docker container ( `dockerimages/harp` ) which default is to use `NODE_ENV=production` which is why I didn't realize it was set for production as default.

To use that image for development you must put:

`$ docker [...] --env NODE_ENV=development [...] dockerimages/harp`